# Some bones not saved in pose library

Tags: rigging, armature

I have a character rig that I am posing (specifically, the MakeHuman rig.) I make a pose and then save it in my pose library with all bones selected. If I then later reset the pose, and then re-apply it from the pose library, certain bones turn out to have not been saved (specifically, chest-1.)

I also notice that when I make my pose, there is no entry for the missing bone in the Action editor. So it's just not getting saved into the pose action at all.

What could cause this?